# Fetch local JSON file from public folder ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, local, fetch-api

I have a problem since two days; I want read a local JSON from my public folder on my React application created with react-app.

This is my project structure:

- public

  - data

    - mato.json (my .JSON file)
- src

  - components

    - App.js

Why I put my file in `public` folder? If I build my project with file in `src` folder, my file will be include in the generated `main.js` by the command `yarn build`.

I want modify my json file without always rebuild my app.

So I can't use code like:

```
import Data from './mato.json'
```

…or:

```
export default { 'mydata' : 'content of mato.json'}
import data from 'mydata';
```

I tried to fetch my .json file but "file scheme" isn't friend with `fetch()` & chrome..

(Chrome error: “index.js:6 Fetch API cannot load file:///D:/projects/data/mato.json. URL scheme "file" is not supported.”)

This is my code for fetch:

```
fetch(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/data/mato.json`)
.then((r) => r.json())
.then((data) =>{
    ReactDOM.render(<App appData={JSON.stringify(data)}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
})
```

It's only works with Firefox. I also tried `mode: 'cors'` does not better.

And of course I don't have any server — it's a local project — so if someone knows how I can read my JSON file locally I will much appreciate.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think your fetch argument is wrong. It should be

```
fetch('data/mato.json')
```

Answer (score 9):

You also need to pass in some `headers` indicating the `Content-Type` and `Accept` as `application/json` to tell your client that you are trying to access and accept some JSON resource from a server.

```
  const getData=()=>{
    fetch('data/mato.json'
    ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    }
    )
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(myJson);
      });
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
  },[])
```

Answer (score 5):

As long as data files are placed in public folder, it should work in Chrome also as in my project.
So, fetch('data/mato.json') is enough for it.

Comment: Thank You @Lex Soft. Have rated all of you.... Quentin and Kevin. information provided is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

**give your JSON file name which is present in the public folder and store the data links**

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("./url.json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ links: data });
        console.log(this.state);
      });
  }
```

Comment: The path is relative, will this access the public folder?

Answer (score -1):

why using fetch? I think the speed is slow...
I think this solution would be better...
you can add this line into your index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="settings.js"></script>
```

then in settings.js you can do this:

```
 window.globalTS= {
  "site_url": "hi.com",
  "home_url": "hello.com"
};
```

now in your components you can get to variables like this:

```
console.log(window.globalTS.site_url);
```

share and comment me your idea, thanks!

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67848787/14267427). If you feel this question is a duplicate, give it a flag, don't just copy and paste the same answer all over the network.

Comment: @Tyler2P thanks, I just gave a flag. both questions has one meanings, just different keywords: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67848787/5008599