# Reading a JSON file from the create-react-app Public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a ipAddress.json file that has the contents:

```
{
  "ipAddress": "11.111.111.111"
}
```

In the public folder i put that ipAddress.json file into an "ipAddress" folder so the path looks like "public/ipAddress/ipAddress.json"

But I cannot read this file.  I am trying

```
const ipAddress = (require(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/ipAddress/ipAddress.json')).ipAddress;
```

using "json-loader" common library.

How do I get this to work?  According to ([Using the Public Folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder))  it should work just fine.

But I get this error:

> Module not found: You attempted to import /ipAddress/ipAddress.json
>   which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports
>   outside of src/ are not supported.

Thank you for any help

Comment: The error literally states what the problem is. Your only workaround might be placing the file inside the src folder

Comment: Alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55298684/8076386

Comment: when I build the project I need to be able to edit that ipAddress.json file which is why I want to put it in the public folder but if I put it into the src folder when I build u cannot access that file

Comment: ok will look at that link thank you

Comment: Read the first answer, there's a reason why it is avoided. Especially to avoid build issues

Comment: @RohitKashyap unfortunately none of that is working.  I already ejected the react-create-app but none of this is telling me how to read from an external file unfortunately.  unless i'm missing something your'e trying to tell me.. putting the file into the src folder won't work for me as when i build.. i won't be able to open up that ipAddress.json file anymore because the file was condensed in the build process.

Comment: You can try reading the file from an external source? Like from a s3 storage service when your app first loads and then saving it to your state or localstorage.

Comment: @RohitKashyap hm ya maybe i'll just have to do that..thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Why not make fetch call to get json data from that file instead?

Comment: @Arturas that's actually what I ended up doing.  I didn't realize that was another option.  I found the information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793310/fetch-local-json-file-from-public-folder-reactjs

Comment: for all you people who downvoted, i'd like to understand why?  i see no reason to downvote this question as i legitimately had this problem

Answer (score 1):

If its just a json object you should be able to create a js file with the data inside a const object. Then export the const as a module.

New JS file to create:

```
const ipAddressJson = {
    ipAddress: "11.111.111.111"
};

module.exports = ipAddressJson;
```

Inside the file you want the json object:

```
import ipAddressJson from 'path-to-the-js-file-above';
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/tender-bash-2hjei

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't allow you to open the json file after building so that i could edit the IP

Answer (score 1):

Why not put your JSON files into your project scope? 
For example, if you have created the react app using create-react-app, the `src` folder will be the default project scope.

Put your JSON files into some folder like `src/data` and simply:

`import data from '../data/somefile.json`

Comment: Because now the JSON is bundled in with the project, requiring you to rebuild every time it's changed.