# 404 Error when trying to fetch json file from public folder in deployed create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, create-react-app

I have a json file in my react project public folder like this

```lisp
public
|
|___Data
    |   test.json
```

In my .tsx file I’m referencing the file like this

```js
fetch(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Data/test.json`,
    {
     headers : {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Accept': 'application/json'
     }
})
 .then(response => response)
```

This works fine in development and when building and serving the app locally (npm run build). But when I try deploy to my Azure web app app service, the site throws a 404 error for that file.

I can also see the file in the Kudu debug console so I know it's getting deployed with the project.

Printing `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to console yields an empty string. Do I need to set this value to something using environment variables? Is there something else that I’m missing with my app service configuration?

I've looked at other similar questions, namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793310/fetch-local-json-file-from-public-folder-reactjs) and the solution did not work for me either.

Comment: If you haven't already, configure a value for `PUBLIC_URL` in Azure. Think this can be done in the portal (details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-app-settings). You can check browser dev tools (Network tab) to see the full URL that the failed request tries to reach and see if it's what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEWEST**

**The React client side project essentially downloads a piece of code to run on the client browser, and will not be related to azure application settings. So its process.env cannot read any azure environment variables.**

The latest updated answer can be your alternative. After a lot of testing, it is found that in the react project, the process.env in the .tsx file is different from the global one.

```
import * as React from 'react';
const {env} = process;
...
public getJsonDataStr = () => {
    const urlBy: string = this.props.urlBy!;
    const url = this.state.url + urlBy + env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL;
    this.setState({ url });
};
```

**For more details**, [you can download my sample code](https://github.com/Jason446620/react-tsx-envparams).

1. Create `.env` file in project.

   [image]
2. npm run build, and deploy build folder.

   [image]
3. Test it.

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

## Method 1

You can set `PUBLIC_URL` in `Application settings` on portal.

**Test Step:**

1. configure on portal.

   [image]
2. Open scm site, click `Environment`.

   [image]
3. open ssh, run command.

   [image]

## Method 2

Try to use `process.env.WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` instead of `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Neither of these methods worked for me. I see both variables in scm, but the site itself they come up as undefined. I the app is hosted on Windows and not linux so I can't use ssh to test their either (unless I just have no idea what I'm doing there either)

Comment: @Jordyn peocess undefined or `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` undefined?

Comment: The latest updated method helped me. Thank you

Comment: The latest update method also helped me! It wasn't obvious from their documentation at all but for some reason `const {env} = process;` and access the environment this way resolves the issue.