# Azure app service externalize variables environment into my Angular web application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I've a two web application (php and angular) hosted on azure web app with two slots (staging and production).

I want swap the two slots (usually from a staging slot into the production slot) . but when i do the swap , the production swap will keep the variable of staging slot ( if the staging point to
a test database, when swap, the production slot will point to the test database)

So, any idea to externalize variables to make the application read the value from externaly ?

Thanks

Comment: where and how i can set the variable in azure web app ?

Comment: Set Application Settings in Configuration page on portal. It should be swapped like the doc said: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#which-settings-are-swapped

Comment: i can't use variable in js file

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you could check if my answer help or not.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the misunderstanding and the delay, I found an [answer for react app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66577247/13586071).

**Like the React client side project, `process.env` cannot read any azure environment variables on Angular project**.

I tested using `.env` file and env.js file, which all failed. Here is the article I was following, you could have a test: https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/

My last suggestion is **hard-code** and make several environmental files to match each of your environments.

For more information about the environmental file, see [Environment Variables in Angular](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-environment-variables)

Comment: I've angular app --> dist folder