# Ionic w/ React environment variables not populated in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic React app and I'm trying to inject some environment variables from a docker-compose file. I saw online that I can access the environment variables via `process.env.VAR_NAME` but that doesn't work for me. I tried to print the whole `process.env` object but no trace of my environment variables.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.21-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

COPY ./build /home/app

WORKDIR /home

RUN npm install -g serve

CMD ["serve", "-s", "app", "-l", "5000"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  myapp:
    image: myapp:local
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5002:5000
    environment: 
      - MY_VAR=testValue
```

In my `index.tsx` file I logged the `process.env` variable and I get the following output:

```js
console.log(process.env)
// {NODE_ENV: "production", PUBLIC_URL: "", WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined, …}

console.log(process.env.MY_VAR)
// undefined
```

Comment: That looks right

Comment: It looks but it doesn't work. From what I saw online, `process.env` is `node-specifi`c. My app is not really a `node` app, so I guess that's why it isn't working? Or maybe because I'm running it with [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)? But I figured, `serve` uses `node` under the hood...

Comment: What do you mean, it's not really a node app? AFAIK, serve is fine -- I use it myself with compose and environment variables.

Comment: Also, try `from node:current-buster-slim`

Comment: Well, it's not a node server, it's an Ionic w/ React client. I suppose there is a difference? I'm not really sure. I'll try `from node:current-buster-slim`

Comment: Not working either, I'm simply clueless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231585/discussion-between-vivere-and-software-engineer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570279/404-error-when-trying-to-fetch-json-file-from-public-folder-in-deployed-create-r/66577247#66577247

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm running my Ionic React app in a docker container as well, and can't figure out why my env variables aren't being read. Based on your comments, it looks like it might be because I've containerized using Nginx to serve my app. Anyway, good luck!