# Azure App service settings not applied with docker

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to Azure Deployment & DevOps,

This time I'm doing a small project to create a NestJS API with Azure App Service, using a customized docker image. Everything was deployed well with the right connection credentials environment variable to the database. However, when I tried to replace these environment variable with

config.service.ts

```
const PORT = process.env.APPSETTING_PORT;
const MODE = process.env.APPSETTING_MODE;
const POSTGRES_HOST = process.env.APPSETTING_POSTGRES_HOST;
const POSTGRES_PORT : any = process.env.APPSETTING_POSTGRES_PORT;
const POSTGRES_USER = process.env.APPSETTING_POSTGRES_USER;
const POSTGRES_PASSWORD = process.env.APPSETTING_POSTGRES_PASSWORD;
const POSTGRES_DATABASE = process.env.APPSETTING_POSTGRES_DATABASE;
```

, after create the app in azure I assign the values with this command on Azure CLI:

`az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <my_rs_group> --name <my_app_name> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=80 APPSETTING_POSTGRES_HOST=<my_host_name>\ APPSETTING_POSTGRES_PORT=5432 APPSETTING_POSTGRES_DATABASE=postgres \ APPSETTING_POSTGRES_USER=<my_user_name> APPSETTING_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<my_host_pw>\ APPSETTING_PORT=80 APPSETTING_MODE=PROD APPSETTING_RUN_MIGRATION=true`

It's been 2 days I'm bothered with this issue and have been going through many similar threads on the site, but I couldn't resolve this issue, the docker container runtime log always show that these environment variables are failed to be applied.

Comment: Have you checked in the Portal if the values were assigned correctly?

Comment: I updated with the photo, they are all assigned correctly

Comment: Is there any sample where one successfully use app settings variables with nodejs on azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answer my own question since I found the thread that resolves this issue, although for some reason this problem is unpopular, linking it down here,

[404 Error when trying to fetch json file from public folder in deployed create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570279/404-error-when-trying-to-fetch-json-file-from-public-folder-in-deployed-create-r/66577247#66577247)

It's vexing that Microsoft didn't make it obvious in their documentation that for nodejs environment, need to set `const {env} = process;` and access it through `PORT = env.APPSETTING_PORT;` for example will help the server to apply the app settings variable properly at docker runtime.

Hope whoever meets this issue will not waste time.