# How to use azure app setting if running function app in docker container

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Below is the trigger for service bus queue trigger in azure function app

```
app.serviceBusQueue('serviceBusQueueTrigger1', {
    connection: 'SERVICE_BUS_CONN_STRING',
    queueName: 'queuename',
    handler: serviceBusQueueTrigger1
});
```

Even when I set `SERVICE_BUS_CONN_STRING` as env variable or pass to docker container, the function app does not start.

`The listener for function 'Functions.serviceBusQueueTrigger1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus: Service Bus account connection string '<full connection string from env var here>' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.`

How one can set app settings for azure function app runnning in docker container?

Below is the docker file that was created by default:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node18

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install
```

Comment: I think this one could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608769/how-and-where-to-define-an-environment-variable-on-azure or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570279/404-error-when-trying-to-fetch-json-file-from-public-folder-in-deployed-create-r/66577247#66577247

Comment: @KKI thanks, but this question talks about setting env variables via portal. Actually, i am trying to start the function in local docker container and able to set the env variables. Only thing is trigger is not reading from env variables while registering the function.
If I provide `connection: process.env.SERVICE_BUS_CONN_STRING` it will show me the complete connection string that it read from env variables and say "Service Bus account connection string '<actual connection string here>' does not exist. "

Comment: @NPC, Can you please share your Docker file?

Comment: @Pavan I have added the docker file to question as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I have created azure servicebus queue trigger function with runtime stack javascript in vs code.
function runs successfully and able to send messages from service bus.

**function code:**

```js
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const  serviceBusConnectionString = process.env.ServiceBusConnectionString;
app.serviceBusQueue('serviceBusQueueTrigger1', {
connection:  'servicebusconnectionstring',
queueName:  'firstqueue',
handler: (message, context) => {
context.log('Service bus queue function processed message:', message);
}
});
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "your-storage account-conn string",
"servicebusconnectionstring": "your-servicebus conn-string",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
}
}
```

I have added below Dockerfile to the project directory.

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Use the official Node.js image as the base image for Azure Functions

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4.0-node18

# Set the working directory

WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

ENV  AzureWebJobsServiceBus="your-servicebus-conn-string"


# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory

COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies

RUN npm install --production

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory

COPY . .

ENV  AzureWebJobsServiceBus="your-servicebus-conn-string"

# Start the Azure Functions runtime

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I was created a azure container registry in portal. by using below commands able to build and push into function app.

```
az acr login --name <REGISTRY_NAME>
docker build -t containerregistryname.azurecr.io/your-image-name:latest .
docker push <LOGIN_SERVER>/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0
az acr update -n <REGISTRY_NAME> --admin-enabled true
```

[image]

I have published my function by using container registry credentials like below command:

```
az functionapp create --name <Function_APP_NAME> --storage-account <STORAGE_NAME> --resource-group <Resource_group> --plan <Plan_Name> --functions-version 4 --runtime dotnet-isolated --image <LOGIN_SERVER>/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0 --registry-username <USERNAME> --registry-password <SECURE_PASSWORD>
```

[image]

Make sure to follow the below for deployment purpose:

[image]

I have added service bus connection string in environment variables of function app. like below:

[image]

I was able to ran the function successfully in azure portal. check below:
**Output:**

[image]